# Rewards for the best answer from the 4th quarter of 2016

Tags: discussion, answers, scheduled-event

Inspired by the mods of a few other communities, I would like to start quarterly rewards for the best answer, and I'd ask the community for the best answers from the past quarter to get an additional reward:

**Please link to an answer which was created from October 1st 2016 through December 31st 2016 and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple favorites submit separate answers to this post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

- **[Answers with most votes from 4th quarter of 2016](http://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/edit/626252)**

Otherwise you can choose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight. Answer can be from you or from someone else.

The highest voted answer of this meta post will be picked up for the reward of 200 points after 2 weeks.

Note: Answer must have 1+ upvote and submitted in the same quarter only. Answer should not be a wiki. Please only propose one post in any answer here so the votes can easily be tallied.

Comment: I like this :) Is there any easy way of reviewing answers in a given period?

Comment: @girbot see the linked query

Comment: D'oh..reading fail.

Comment: I wonder what other metrics we could use to find underappreciated answers? Maybe view count? [Most Viewed Questions in three months](http://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/edit/627338). I guess I should really rework that to be most viewed answers.

Comment: @Daniel Ultimately, the metric I will use is votes here. Any question is eligible for nomination, as long as it has one up vote! I hope to see several more nominations!

Comment: I really hope there will be more nominations! Please, nominate more answers! If there are any favorites you've written, or answers to questions that really bailed you out, nominate them!

Comment: @DanielBallinger That query seems broken. Some of the first posts on the link have like 17 views. The first one only has 42.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Does it work now. I was playing with the p.PostTypeId. Had changed it from 1 to 2 to see if I could measure the answer views. I didn't realize that changes were persisted to the linked query.

Comment: Seems much more useful, yep! Thinking about nominating any? :)

Comment: I am humbled and happy to see that many have found one of my answers that useful. Can we nominate something from September? This answer by sfdcfox: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141330/help-on-invokable-apex-test-class-and-future-callout-apex-test-class/141334#141334 - was one of the most fundamentally helpful posts I have seen (for me at least) it is so simple and yet changed the way I think about mocks. No more needlessly checking endpoints, setting values, having huge class to test callouts. Seems so obvious yet the SF examples led me in the opposite direction

Comment: @Eric Considering this is the first time we've run this contest and it's close...feel free to nominate. At this point I'm just trying to get more participation. I may DQ anyway and award to something from the correct quarter, but the main purpose here is to bring more attention to useful answers.

Comment: Just locking this so the votes can't change moving forward!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eric's [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/147026/2995) on [What is suggested approach to transfer VF pages to be lightning ready](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147023/2995) is creative, novel, and looks like something I will imitate in the future. He freely provided a template that will help ease the transition to SLDS.

Comment: I saw Eric and got excited.. :(

Comment: @EricSSH You can of course nominate any answer including your own.

Comment: I ran the query and after much thought, I too thought Eric's answer was of high value

Answer (score 7):

I would like to nominate another [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/149806/2995) by Eric on [How to convert a Visualforce apex:pageMessages to be lightning style](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/149797/2995). It inspired me to write a component that can add an arbitrary number of page messages as toasts, which I intend to share there when I get a chance.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to nominate an answer by Mohith on [How does component.set works underneath the hood](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146142/how-does-component-set-works-underneath-the-hood) . It cleared explained how lightning component works underneath the hood.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to nominate this answer by sfdcfox:

[Help on Invokable Apex Test class and @Future callout Apex test Class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141330/help-on-invokable-apex-test-class-and-future-callout-apex-test-class/141334#141334)

It was one of the most fundamentally helpful posts I have seen (for me at least) it is so simple and yet changed the way I think about mocks.

No more needlessly checking endpoints, setting values, having huge class to test callouts. Seems so obvious yet the SF examples led me in the opposite direction

Thanks @sfdcfox

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add another one here that I found interesting: [Dan Wooding](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/31089/dan-wooding)'s answer on [remove advertising on login page of Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/143928/2995). Pretty interesting question that I had often wondered myself. I especially like the recommendation to use https://blank.org/ as a replacement url.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, finally getting around to some nominations.

This nomination is from [How to avoid instantiating object inside a loop?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143891/how-to-avoid-instantiating-object-inside-a-loop/)

[Adrian's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/143896/24889) was initially quite short, but was updated to include some benchmarks. To me, this is the type of answer that goes the extra mile.

This answer caters to beginners and those just looking for some quick information (concise recommendation with an easily understandable example).

It also caters to experts and detail-oriented devs. We all know (or at least I *hope* we all know) that premature optimization is the root of all evil. Getting some hard data that validates the original claims of the answer is good, but knowing how much of a difference setting fields using dot-notation vs using the sObject constructor makes is vital to making informed decisions.